# Angularjs how to allow $ in json of $http requests

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Angularjs trims all the $ in the JSON of $http requests.

In the code below, instead of `{"s": {"id":  {"$oid": "11" }}}` only `{"s": {"id":{}}}` is sent to the server.

```
 var p={"s": {"id":  {"$oid": "11" }}};
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'n/s',
    params: p
 }).success(function() ....
```

I have seen this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1463 , but i am unable to do the workaround.

Comment: Try sending JSON as a string?

Comment: I am looking for neater way in angularjs, rather than hacks on server side.

Comment: converting JSON as string is different then sending an object, since each key of the object becomes a parameter to the HTTP request, while just converting JSON to string does not.

Comment: shall we consider this a bug in angularjs

Comment: i am looking for a fix.. since the service that i am using is taking up lots of $ in it.

Comment: Can't really think of anything. The link you posted has mentioned couple of work arounds with mongo. You can also post this to Angular.js community.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: nopes,, not yet ,, converting JSON as string is different then sending an object, since each key of the object becomes a parameter to the HTTP request, while just converting JSON to string does not ,, is one option which ppl are using. Another option is changing the server to have some escape chars. Check this for more info :  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1463 i haven't been tracking this for some time.